# In a mesocyclone, why does wind shear create a horizontal axis of spinning air?

Tags: meteorology, severe-weather, mesoscale-meteorology

Take a look at this picture.[image: Mesocyclone beginning]

Moist updrafts interact with highly-sheared upper-level winds, which sets up a horizontal vortex. But *why?* What causes the air to be forced downward and to the right, then continue rising (also to the right)?

Comment: there is vertical shear in the mesocyclone environment. Think about the tilting term in the vorticity tendency equation.

Comment: https://sites.psu.edu/pmarkowski/how-tornadoes-form/ seems to offer a nicer explanation for why it happens... basically if I get it still (it has been a long time since I've looked at such subjects!), [in the Northern Hemisphere] having south winds below and the west winds aloft torques the air in between kind of like how an American football would spin by applying two different horizontal directions of motion with your hands at the top and bottom?